# NexusPipelineApi.Resume exception

Tags: content-editor

I am on SC 9.2.  When I try to edit an item as a non-administrator that is under workflow, I am getting the following error.  The item is getting checked out, and a new version is created, but the checkout does not complete due to the error, and I am unable to edit the item.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any clues about the real source of the problem, except that it looks like something related to licensing (which is good).  Log files are not providing any more detail, even with DEBUG logging level. Since this appears to be WebAPI related, I tried using Fiddler, I see a 504 Receive Failure when Sitecore connects to XConnect.  The Chrome debugger does not seem to be providing any more information either.

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CheckOut.Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the workflow did not include WorkflowState:Descendants access.  It did have Workflow State:Write access.  Once Descendants access was granted, I was able to successfully invoke the content editor.